# Alternative way to instantiate a class not implements the parent interfaces

Tags: java, android, inheritance, assign

At somewhere, that I can not remember, I read about an alternative way to instatiate a object:

Generally, we instantiate (and assign) this way:

```
User userObj = new User();
userObj.setId(1);
userObj.setName("Foo");
```

An alternative way could be:

```
User userObj = new User()
{{
    setId(1);
    setName("Foo");
}}
```

I was using this alternative, and it works.

**1) Anyone knows what is it? Where is Java documentation link that metion about it?**

I stop to use this because I was having problems with interfaces that `ClassName` implements, but the alternative way don't implements. Oo

```
public class User implements Serializable
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //public Getters and Setters
}
```

**2) When I try to serialize and use it (passing from one activity to another, using:
`putExtra(String, Serializable)`
it will throw NotSerializableException. Why?**

*Edit 1: An anonnymous class also implements the parent 'implementations', like Serializable from ClassName?*

Comment: Instance initialization blocks combined with anonymous classes.

Comment: I suspect the answer to your first question has absolutely nothing to do with your second, nor the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using anonymous class with initialization block. So it's just an equivalent to the:

```
SubClass extends ClassName{
   {
      classObj.setParam1(1);
      classObj.setParam2(1);
   }

}

new SubClass();
```

There is nothing wrong with this construction - but please notice that you are not creating object of ClassName class, but object of SubClass class.

As I said you are using anonymous class (class without name). This is bad - cause while serialization / deserialization JVM should exactly know what is the class of serialization data, so basically - don't use anonymous classes if you want to serialize them.

Comment: Although some summaries at the end, it was a great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1.: This construct ist called "anonymous class".

Ad 2.: I bet your class contains a field which is not `Serializable`.

Comment: No. I just have primitive type attributes, like float and int.

Comment: Please add the contents of your class to the post.